# In Azure AD B2C, what is AdminClientEncryptionKeyContainer for?

Tags: configuration, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been setting up custom policies in Azure AD B2C that take elements from a number of different examples including email invite signup, social and local accounts, and api connectors.

Because of that, I've pulled together code from approximately 10 different example repos and 30 pages of Microsoft documentation.

Now I'm going back through everything I've built and trying to note, more completely, what pieces of the infrastructure are responsible for what functionality.

In the B2C Tenant, in the Identity Experience Framework page, under the Policy Keys page, I have an entry for `AdminClientEncryptionKeyContainer` (auto-prefixed as `B2C_1A_AdminClientEncryptionKeyContainer`) which I have no recollection of creating, and can find very little reference to on Google.

Where did B2C_1A_AdminClientEncryptionKeyContainer come from and what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Azure AD B2C tenant the B2C_1A_AdminClientEncryptionKeyContainer Policy Key is created automatically when you create a new Policy Key with the "Options" of "Manual".

If you're following the Microsoft Docs tutorial for user flows and custom policies, this will be the step when you [Create the Facebook key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#create-the-facebook-key).

My assumption, though I don't know for certain, is that it's required for encrypting the Secret of a manually created policy key.